# In python, combine the values of 2 dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python, and I have two questions regarding dictionary in python.

1. I have `dict1` (where the values is already a `list`), then I have `dict2`with the same `keys` as `dict1`, I want to add the new value to the `list` of values in `dict1`. How can I write it? Can you show it with an example?

   ```
   dict1 = {'uid': ['u1'], 'sid': ['s1'], 'os': ['os1']}

   dict2 = {'uid': ['u2'], 'sid': ['s2'], 'os': ['os2']}
   ```

   Expected output:

   ```
   dict1 = {'uid': ['u1', 'u2'], 'sid': ['s1', 's2'], 'os': ['os1', 'os2']}
   ```

---

2. I will be process a lot of lines in a text file, with each line creating a new dictionary. Here is the idea of my code:

   ```
   count = 0

   for line in f:

       if count == 0:
           dict1 = parse_qs(line)
           count = count+1
       else:
           dict2 = parse_qs(line)
           #combine dict1 with dict 2, and assign the new dict to dict1
   ```

Is there a better way that uses less memory or runs faster (still using dictionary)?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Don't create multiple dicts. Create one `defaultdict(list)` and let your parser append values to that.

Comment: I'm using the urlparse, so it automatically gives me a dict. And that's the best way I've tried to clean my data. But still thanks.

Comment: Fairly sure this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're apparently not allowed to rewrite you parser, you can do:

```
for k in dict1:
    dict1[k].extend(dict2.get(k, []))
```

You can drop the `.get` and use direct subscription if the keys from both dicts are always matching.

```
for k in dict1:
    dict1[k].extend(dict2[k])
```

Otherwise, you can create one `defaultdict(list)` and let your parser append values to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
for key in dict1.keys():
     if dict2.has_key(key):
         dict1[key].extend(dict2[key])
```

if you are using `python3` you can use `key in dict2` instead of `dict2.has_key(key)`.

**Result**

```
{'os': ['os1', 'os2'], 'sid': ['s1', 's2'], 'uid': ['u1', 'u2']}
```

Comment: using `extend` would be better here. `.extend(dict2[key])`. `dict2` might have values of len > 1

Comment: And `key in dict2` has been preferred over `has_key` since forever, `has_key` is even gone in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the two dictionaries anymore then you can do this:

```
def merge_dict(dict1, dict2):
    for k in dict1:
        try:
            dict1[k].extend(dict2[k])
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return dict1
```

Else if you want to preserve them both for future use, try this

```
def merge_dict(dict1, dict2):
    new_dict = {}
    keys = dict1.keys() + dict2.keys()
    for k in keys:
        try:
            new_dict[k] = dict1[k]
        except KeyError:
            new_dict[k] = dict2[k]
            continue
        try:
            new_dict[k]+= dict2[k]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return dict1
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful to you.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

# ------ for dict1 -------#

u1 = [1,2,3]
s1 = ['a','b','c']
x1 = [10,100,1000]

# ------ for dict2 -------#

u2 = [4,5,6]
s2 = ['d','e','f']
x2 = ['aa','bb','cc']

dict1 = {1:u1,2:s1,3:x1}
dict2 = {1:u2,2:s2,3:x2}

dict3 = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
     dict3[a].append(b)

#for a, b in dict3.items():
#    print(a, b)

print dict3
```